# Jenkins Promote Build across different pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In my workplace, we are using a monolithic repo. It contains many project and micro services that run on different Jenkins pipeline. I know that using [Promoted Build Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin), we can promote build of tested artifact.

However as our projects depend on projects that run on a separate pipeline, I am wondering if the [Promoted Build Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin) is able to promote artifact to a different pipeline. Or can the pipeline that is running head over to a separate "place" to take the last tested artifact and use it as part of its own pipeline criteria?

The reason we want to do this is because of integration test that depend on the existent of another build artifact. We want to be able to test on the latest build artifact that is on another pipeline. Would be even better if we can select base on the tag/version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should treat each pipeline dependency as any other dependency.

Set up an artifact repo like [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) to be used as source of artifacts.
This way you can ask for latest or tagged version of an artifact inside your pipeline and push to this repo your own artifacts when the build succeed.

Comment: You could also use [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget). There's a plugin for the integration: https://plugins.jenkins.io/inedo-proget

Comment: @KarlHarnagy You may wish to turn this comment in an answer (with some more details on how it solves the problem)

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai having a artifact repo seems like a good way to handle that. I will look read up more about it first.

Comment: @KarlHarnagy , If you have setup before, could you add an answer and briefly explain how it should be used?